# Joomla save update delete the custom table data using frontend and backend

Tags: joomla, save, components

I have a employee table in Joomla, my requirement is that, from front-end each employee edit, update, delete their information as well admin too from back-end do the same.

I don't know how to do this, may be I have to create a component for this or else?
Please guide me.

I see the code in  com_user in built component, but it is very hard to understand..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code generated from the Joomla component creator to do the administration code. Then you can hack it to also edit from the front end. http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/

Answer (score 0):

You've not mentioned what version of Joomla you're using ,but the com_user component is a core Joomla component to manage your users login and credentials, not necessarily an employee table(though you might be using it that way).  If it doesn't meet your needs, I'd suggest looking at the many extensions that Joomla has in their [clients-a-communities/user-management extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/user-management) before you hack that, and see if someone else has already solved the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the standard Joomla MVC framework to create a component for this. A very good tutorial available at Joomla Docs
for [Developing a Basic Component](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Developing_a_Basic_Component)

In a nutshell:

1. You need to create front end component for users to access/edit content
2. Create backend component for administrator use

You can restrict certain actions to registered users by using the permission settings of Joomla. You can follow the below documentation:
[Adding ACL rules to your component](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_ACL_rules_to_your_component)